# Copying a certain number of characters from one pointer to another

Tags: c, string, pointers, char

I have a source pointer (`pSource`) and a goal pointer (`pGoal`). I also have a number of characters (`n`) that need to be copied to the `pGoal` from `pSource`.

I thought that I can just copy what's in the `pSource` to `pGoal` and move both pointers to the next location. (Both are pointing at the start at the beginning).

```
for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
     pGoal+i = pSource+i;
}
```

Comment: `*(pGoal+i) = *(pSource+i);` or `pGoal[i] = pSource[i];`

Comment: I am pretty sure you're getting a lot of compiler's warnings on your code. Pay attention to those - they are your friend.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that your pointers are of type `char *`, the correct way of doing this is:

```
for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
    *(pGoal+i) = *(pSource+i);
    // or pGoal[i] = pSource[i]
}
```

You can also check [memcpy](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstring/memcpy/)

Comment: It works until my n is <= to the string length in pSource.

Comment: @Sanlyn, Yes it is so. You should always check the limits of your buffers to avoid errors.

Comment: so how can i make it that if the n is > than the string in pSource it still works. i need to finish each pGoal copy with a '\0'.

Comment: It would be useful to post more code. One think I can suggest is to initialize ```n``` to be the length of ```pSource``` and to alloc enough memory for ```pGoal```.